# Unix grep confusion

Tags: command-line, grep

I am doing an assignment for school and using putty to complete the assignment. The format of the assignment does not allow for much variation and thus only one answer is sufficient enough to allow me to move on to the next question. They also want the shortest possible pathnames and commands used to get to the answer.

Your current directory is sample_dir. Find the records in cars2 that contain the string "ford" and display the number of characters in the result. 
sample_dir2

```
 -- sample_dir
    |-- admin
    |-- cambridge
    |   `-- security
    |       |-- annex
    |       `-- parking
    |-- history.exe
    |-- markham
    |   |-- annex
    |   |-- building1
    |   `-- parking
    `-- stenton
        |-- f1
        |-- f12
        |-- f2
        |-- gen_ed
        |   |-- Holidays
        |   `-- cars2
        |-- lib_arts
        |   `-- english.txt
        `-- phone_directory
        |   |-- Holidays
        |   `-- cars2
        |-- lib_arts
        |   `-- english.txt
        `-- phone_directory
```

I've tried 
`grep -c ford stenton/gen_ed/cars2` and different options using `grep`. Is this along the right path or am I way off?

Comment: One of the difficulties in these sorts of questions is that there are a myriad of ways to achieve the end result. In your specific case the result depends a lot on what you have been previously taught—which we don't know.

Comment: This is ULI101 at Seneca College, which we get year after year.  [All assignments **"MUST consist of the student’s OWN work"**.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211656/copying-and-relative-home#comment358558_211656)

Answer (score 3):

To display the lines including ford in any cars2 file, you could use:

```
find . -name cars2 -exec grep ford {} \;
```

To count the global number of characters of the records:

```
find . -name cars2 -exec grep -h ford {} \; | wc -c
```

Comment: Another option is `find -name cars2 | xargs grep ford | wc -c`.

Comment: Rather than using `find`, since we know the structure of the directories, wouldn't use of globbing be more elegant? Something more like `grep ford stenton/*/cars2 | wc -c`?

Answer (score 1):

The answer would be:

```
 grep "ford" stenton/gen_ed/cars2 | wc -c
```

Comment: This answer doesn't provide an answer that has not been given already. Recommend deletion.

Comment: He attempted this question multiple times giving him/her the answer would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
grep ford stenton/gen_ed/cars2 -r
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you would do this is simple

```
grep ford stenton/gen_ed/cars2 | wc -m
```